# Why does it appear in R that lapply is decaying integer64 to numeric and how can I avoid it?

Tags: r, types, lapply

I'm not sure I understand what is happening in the following simple code snippet:

```
require(bit64)
foo <- as.integer64(c(20,30,40))
foo #shows integer64
lapply(foo, class) #says numeric!
```

Why is that happening in the call to lapply? Is there a way to avoid it? Internally in my `lapply` function I am doing some integer64 arithmetic and this I found is what was breaking it..

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906843/how-to-void-type-conversion-in-rs-apply-bit64-example

Answer (score 0):

Something in the guts of `lapply` is doing it. Instead, try applying over the indices and calling a function:

```
> lapply(1:length(foo),function(x){class(foo[x])})
[[1]]
[1] "integer64"

[[2]]
[1] "integer64"

[[3]]
[1] "integer64"
```

Comment: Combine that with the fact that `c()` drops the S3 class attribute (which is known) and you have an answer.

Comment: Thanks - as Spacedman points out the question is duplicate, I just didn't find the original on my first couple searches.

Comment: there's a c.integer64 - it looks like `as.list` in `lapply` that drops everything.